# Running Java Code from Within Java

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [using eval in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)
>   [Loading external source code and using them internally (by re-compiling or something)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981750/loading-external-source-code-and-using-them-internally-by-re-compiling-or-someth)

I want to simulate an 'eval' in Java such that the function takes in a String (some source code), compiles it, runs it, and spits back the return value.

I know I can compile it using the JavaCompiler API, but I am unsure the best way to actual run the code like this. Runtime.exec feels too heavy for this task... I don't want to spawn another java process each time I run this 'eval' function just to evaluate '30+20' or something. This would be slow and resource intensive.

Finally, this must be able to run ANY java code, so relying on a scripting language evaluator inside Java won't do (ex. if the input is more complex Java than just '30+20')

Any alternatives?

Comment: Also possible dup of [How could I call Java code dynamically ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588242/139010)

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this myself, but you can write your own ClassLoader and load the bytecodes into the JVM.  There is a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Security/Fundamentals/magercises/ClassLoader/help.html) on this.