# Coverting string to java code

Tags: java, dynamic

I have a string constructed at run time like

```
str = "a+dataValue(i)";
```

where 'a' is a variable, `'dataValue(i)'` is a function with argument i

Now I have a function where I want to use string str as part of code. For example

```
 public void func()
     {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
          Sytem.out.println(converted_to_java_source(str)); //(i.e.) a+dataValue(i);  it should be converted at runtime not compile time 

     }
```

I need output like as follows:

```
 when a = 2; dataValue(i) returns i; n = 5
 On call to func it should print
 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1981919/365188

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the Java equivalent of the `eval` function / method in dynamically typed languages like JavaScript, Perl, Python and so on.  Unfortunately there isn't one.

There are various ways to do this kind of thing in Java, but they are all expensive, and come with a variety of other down-sides.

My advice is to look for another (easier / cheaper) way to meet your requirement.

---

If you really need to go down the `eval` route, then here are some related Q/A's which give a reasonable coverage of the options.:

- [Is there an eval() function in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)
- [Is there a java equivalent of the python eval function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143343/is-there-a-java-equivalent-of-the-python-eval-function)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [Byte Code Engineering Libraray (BCEL)](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/). In either case, things can get messy and overcomplicated so I would recommend what Stephen suggested and try to look for another way.

You could, for instance, use som `if` `else` statements to call your function in the *usual* manner, maybe something like:

```
String functionName = "...";
if (functionName.toLowerCase().equals("someMethodName")
{
     someMethodName(someParams);
}
```